# ANN Performance Using Separate Namespaces

Tags: vespa

I am trying to perform ANN, but my data is split into partitions or "tenants." Searches are always restricted to a single tenant, which represents a small percentage of the total documents.

I first tried implementing this using a filter on a tenant string attribute. However, I encountered [this piece of documentation](https://blog.vespa.ai/using-approximate-nearest-neighbor-search-in-real-world-applications/), that suggests the performance will be poor:

> There is a small problem here however. If the eligibility list is small in relation to the number of items in the graph, skipping occurs with a high probability. This means that the algorithm needs to consider an exponentially increasing number of candidates, slowing down the search significantly. To solve this, Vespa.ai switches over to a brute-force search when this occurs. The result is a efficient ANN search when combined with filters.

What's the best way to solve my problem? Will partitioning my data into separate [namespaces](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/documents.html) trigger the creation of a separate HNSW graph per namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance will be fine, the query planner will just choose to not use the ANN index for these queries. You'll find lots of details on this topic, including how to tune this, in this blog post: https://blog.vespa.ai/constrained-approximate-nearest-neighbor-search/

If *all* your queries are towards a single tenant which is a small percentage of the total documents I don't think you necessarily need to create an HNSW index at all, but this depends on the absolute numbers and the largest "small percentage".

(Namespaces are not relevant here - their *only* purpose is to safely add a string to ids so that you can have multiple sources of ids and still be guaranteed global uniqueness.)

Comment: All my queries are not towards a single tenant. Each tenant has ~few million docs, and each tenant will receive search queries, but only within their own documents. There are a few thousand tenants. Still trying to figure out how to optimize performance for this use case.

Comment: Above, I meant "If *no* query searches more than a single tenant". If that is never needed I think it would probably be cheaper to go without an HNSW index with these numbers. You can test with and without by setting approximate true/false in the NN operator on a single node. This allows you to extrapolate total query throughput, but latency without approximization will be lower the more nodes you add (per group). There's no way to create multiple separate HNSW indexes in the same document type, but thousands of small indexes would probably not be cost effective anyway.

Comment: Note also that write cost will be much lower without the HNSW index, that must be taken into account in addition to the query side.

Comment: Thank you Jon for volunteering your knowledge and expertise; it's been super helpful! I will start by benchmarking without HNSW and see if that works for us.

Comment: @masterllama see also https://blog.vespa.ai/billion-scale-knn-part-two/ on these tradeoffs, exact versus approximate, impact on indexing speed and more.